# I'm trying to reduce brackets in math equations down to one number using a recursive function and I keep getting a list index out of range error

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to search for the inner most left hand bracket then find its partner and evaluate the expression in those brackets, after that replace the whole bracket and expression with one number and call the function again on the new list until I'm left with just one number after evaluating all brackets from most inward to most outward. I'm sure there's a whole load of plugins I could use to get that but this is trying to be a learning exercise so I don't think that would help me much.

```
def opperation(l):

  if l[1] == "+":
      return add(l[0], l[2])
  if l[1] == "-":
      return subtract(l[0], l[2])
  if l[1] == "*":
      return multiply(l[0], l[2])
  if l[1] == "/":
      return divide(l[0], l[2])
  if l[1] == "^":
      return power(l[0], l[2])
```

here opperation is handed a list of length 3 which would be of the form `"number"` `"opperation"` `"number"`

```
def howdeep(l):
  level=0
  maxlevel=0
  for it in l:
      if it == "(":
          level=level+1
      if it == ")":
        level=level-1
      if level>maxlevel:
          maxlevel=level
  return maxlevel
```

how deep is just used to find how many brackets deep the program will have to go to find the bottom bracket

```
def condense(brackl):
  depth=howdeep(brackl)
  d=0
  index=0

  while d<depth:
      if(brackl[index]=="("):
          d=d+1
      index=index+1

  tempindex=index
  print(index)
  print(tempindex)
  print(brackl)

  while brackl[tempindex] != ")" or brackl[index] != "(":
      tempindex=tempindex+1
  tempindex=tempindex+1

  if len(brackl)>1:
      brackl[index]=opperation(brackl[index+1:index+4])
      del brackl[index+1:index+5]
      condense(brackl)
  else:
      return brackl[0]
```

condense is supposed to be the main part of the program to do all the reducing, but whenever I run it I get a list index out of range error on the line

```
    "while brackl[tempindex] != ")" or brackl[index] != "(":"
```

I tried to debug a little bit and when I print out the index at this point I get 9 which is one more than I expected but still shouldn't be out of bounds given the list I fed into it

main

```
l=["(","3","+","4","*","(","4","*","(","3","+","8",")",")",")"]

print (condense(l))
```

so to summarize I want to know

1. Why is it saying the indicies is out of range?
2. And why does it gets to 9 when it should stop at 8?

Comment: You could consider `pylex/yacc` for such problems. Those use grammars to evaluate arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you add to index even after you have found a result which increases the number one more than it should be. As such, you should change your while loop to:

```
while d<depth:
    if(brackl[index]=="("):
        d=d+1
    index=index+1
index -= 1
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: If i do that it doesnt find the inner most bracket to work outwards from there, it just tries to solve the first braket it comes across

Comment: I meant the first while loop, and that sounds like a secondary error.

Comment: dont i need to move the index forward no matter what though? not incrementing when i find the first or second opening bracket would cause it to fall behind